# In Redux Observable how to get image size after img has loaded

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, redux-observable

I'm trying to get the dimensions of an image after it has loaded. I've received the URL from an api response, created an image instance and onload I want to dispatch the GET_IMAGE_DIMENSIONS action passing the image width as payload. My code is below.

However, it seems that because of the onload function, the GET_IMAGE_DIMENSIONS action is out of the original mergeMap scope but I'm unsure of how to fix it. Or is the problem something else?

```
const getImageDimensionsEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS').pipe(
    mergeMap(payload => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = payload.image_url;
      img.onload = function() {
        return Observable.of({
          type: 'GET_IMAGE_DIMENSIONS',
          img: img.width
        });
      };
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the dimensions as a part of the chain you'll need to return an Observable inside `mergeMap`. This inner Observable will manually emit the dimensions to the chain and then complete.

```
const getImageDimensionsEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS').pipe(
    mergeMap(payload => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = payload.image_url;

      return new Observable(observer => {
        img.onload = function() {
          observer.next({
            type: 'GET_IMAGE_DIMENSIONS',
            img: img.width
          });
          observer.complete();
        };
      });
    })
  );
```